# CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs() - using ToList() to reduce transaction cost

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have two code examples :

```cs
var container = new CloudBlobContainer("address");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs();
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    //Do somthing
}
```

and this :

```cs
var container = new CloudBlobContainer("address");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs().ToList();
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
     //Do somthing
}
```

Will the second example give any advantage "transaction-wise" ?
How many transaction are made to the blob storage in each example ?

Comment: Im not sure that you stated your question as you intended, when reading your comment on my blob post found here: http://toolheaven.net/post/How-to-do-a-fast-recursive-local-folder-tofrom-azure-blob-storage-synchronization.aspx#comment

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, I would say the `.Where(...).SingleOrDefault()` makes all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: It appears this question is in reference to a [blog post by Martin Ingvar Kofoed Jensen](http://toolheaven.net/post/How-to-do-a-fast-recursive-local-folder-tofrom-azure-blob-storage-synchronization.aspx#comment).  The difference between this question and that question is the call to `.Where(...).SingleOrDefault()`.  Because LINQ is lazy-evaluated, at the stage of `Container.ListBlobs()` it is still an `IEnumerable` and hasn't yet called the REST API (no data has been retrieved).  As soon as a result operation occurs (such as `ToList()` or `SingleOrDefault()`), the data is downloaded.  Since a non-lazy operation is called on a lazy list inside the loop in the following code, it incurs a transaction for every loop iteration:

```
foreach (string filePath in allFilesInStartFolder)
{
    string fileHash = GetFileHashFromCache(filePath, lastSync);

    /* Checking for added files */
    var blob = blobs.Where(b => b.LocalPath == filePath).SingleOrDefault();
    // ^^ This is a non-lazy op on a lazy evalution, so it causes a REST call.
    ....
}
```

---

Regarding the question as it's actually written: Both code snippets will incur a [single transaction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx) (up to 5,000 blobs).  I tested both code snippets in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)/[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), and I only see a [single API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) to generate the list of blobs (replaced our storage name with {mystore}):

```
https://{mystore}.blob.core.windows.net/
    {mystore}?restype=container&comp=list&delimiter=%2F&timeout=90
```

According to the documentation for [List Blobs REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx), up to 5,000 results can be returned in a single call.  So if you want to list all blobs in the entire container, it will take at most (# blobs / 5000) transactions.

Comment: What about counting? Apparently I can count >5000 files without a problem